# C'è differenza o equivalenza fra 'che' e 'perché' in "Elberich è lì *che*/*perché* aspetta di essere assunto

Tags: grammar

> Elberich è lì *che* aspetta di essere assunto.

È possibile che il *che* lì sopra equivalga a *perché*, cioè:

> Elberich è lì perché aspetta di essere assunto.

Se non è così, che differenza sintattica e grammaticale c'è fra quel *che* e quel *perché*?

Se, invece, è così, non dovrebbe quel *che* essere scritto *ché*?

Answer (score 5):

Secondo me non sono la stessa cosa.

Nella prima frase:

> Elberich è lì che aspetta di essere assunto.

il che è usato per indicare uno stato. Con aspettare suona male, ma il *che aspetta* può essere trasformato nel participio presente *aspettante*.

Nella seconda frase:

> Elberich è lì perché aspetta di essere assunto.

il perché introduce chiaramente una causa e non può essere trasformato in un participio presente.

Non sono un linguista, però non mi sembrano identiche le due forme (anche se non sono ovviamente lontane tra loro).

Comment: Hai ragione, d'altronde basta cambiare la frase per vedere che _lì che_ non significa _lì perché_. Per esempio: _È lì che non fa niente_ vuol dire che è lì a non fare niente, non vuol dire che è lì perché non fa niente. Quel _che_ è un pronome relativo anche se la formula è diventata un modo di dire congelato (non posso usarla in modo creativo, _Vive lì che fa il fornaio_ non si può mica dire).